# Navigation using one activity and one toolbar with multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

In order to have a persistent toolbar in my app (I want to animate/morph the icons on the toolbar when switching to a different screen), I used an architecture which consists of 1 activity, 1 toolbar and a main fragment, which gets replaced as needed.

In order to create proper navigation (including the device's back button) I need to let the activity (and/or the toolbar) know which fragment is currently being displayed.

I was thinking of creating a private Integer ArrayList - could be called fragmentNumberHistory - which stores the history of the fragment order displayed with the last being the current the number of the current fragment, simulating the back stack a little bit, only for "fragment id's".

Question: although this strategy seems to work, it feels like an unclean work-around. Is there a textbook way to implement this? I would have thought one could ask the FragmentManager which fragment is currently being displayed in a specific container but that doesn't seem to be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to implement an interface to manage backstack.
[Here](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/10/01/handling-back-button-press-inside-fragments/) is a good blog post which would help you understand this process

Comment: Groovey, at first sight, that looks like it's exactly what I need! I'll see if I can get it to run ... (tried to upvote, but lacking reputation :P)

Comment: Cool. Let me know if you face any other issues.

Comment: Works like a charm for the main fragments ... need to fiddle around with it a bit more to make it work with my nested fragments (viewPager in the main fragment) but I'm confident I'll pull that off with this approach :) Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: glad I could help. Cheers!